# Setting name of usql job invoked from data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory, u-sql

Is it possible to set name of USQL job when invoking it using Data factory ?

Currently when my USQL jobs are invoked using Data Factory, Data Lake Analytics job view shows just GUID as a name for those jobs. My goal is to easily spot what the job is about and GUID doesn't help unless I open the job and see its code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying to set the name of the job automatically based on certain parameters? And are you using ADF v2 or v1? The below answer is for v2:

Currently you can set the name of your U-SQL job in the JSON field of the U-SQL activity (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-data-lake-analytics) under "Data Lake Analytics U-SQL Activity"), or by clicking on the U-SQL activity and changing the Name field under the General tab (if you're using the Visual Tools). Changing the name in either of those fields should result in a job name in ADLA of "-.  If you're not getting that even with changing the name, or you're trying to customize the name via parameters, we can debug further.

Comment: Thank you. We're using v1 - is it possible to do it for v1?

Comment: Unfortunately that is not possible in ADF v1.

Comment: @mabasile_MSFT Does this support adding dynamic parameters ? The UI definitely does not allow this